# I need to break original image into sub parts based on shape

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working with the following input image:

[image]

I want to extract all the boxes inside original images as an individual images with position so that i can also construct it after doing some operations on it. Currently I'm trying to detect contours on the image using OpenCV. But the problem is it also extracts all the words inside the box. The output is coming something like this:

[image]

Is there is any way where i can set the dimensions of box to be taken or something else is required for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly simple approach:

1. Convert to grayscale.
2. Invert the image (to avoid getting top level contour detected around whole image -- we want the lines white and background black)
3. Find external contours only (we don't have any nested boxes).
4. Filter contours by area, discard the small ones.

You could possibly also filter by bounding box dimensions, etc. Feel free to experiment.

### Example Script

Note: for OpenCV 2.4.x

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('cnt2.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - gray # invert

contours,heirarchy = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for contour in contours:
  area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
  if area > 500.0:
    cv2.drawContours(img,[contour],-1,(0,255,0),1)

cv2.imwrite('cnt2_out.png', img)
```

### Example Output

[image: result]

Comment: I'm Trying your code with http://i.imgur.com/sqM3I1T.jpg image but it doesn't work can you help me with it.